# Libcurl chunked http message received callback

Tags: http, libcurl, comet

Does libcurl expose some callback to be called when chunked http message is received?
One server establishs comet-based http connection with a client. 
So client sends request to open connection using regular http,
server responses with chunked http message which contains information to be processed by a client. Using opened connection several messages might be sent by server to a client on one http request. Each must be processed differently.

Is there a way to get this messages once their are sent without waiting for conection to be closed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

libcurl does not expose the chunk limits/borders by default, if that's what you're asking. libcurl will "decode" chunked encoded data and call the write callback with the payload contents, without revealing the chunks to the application. libcurl may then call the write callback one or more times for each incoming chunk.

Optionally, you go the more hard-core route and ask libcurl to deliver the data "unencoded", so that your callback gets the entire thing, including the chunked-encoding meta-data so that you get to decode that yourself. You can tell libcurl to do that by using the [CURLOPT_HTTP_CONTENT_DECODING](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_HTTP_CONTENT_DECODING.html) option.

Comment: Thank you very much for such quick response, Daniel. It is absolutely amazing and cool that everyone can get an answer from the library owner.I can't describe my emotions :)

Comment: Tried with CURLOPT_HTTP_CONTENT_DECODING equal 0.
Still I do not get write callback being called. So while I receive chunked messages without getting last chunked message with 0 content length as a final message, write callback won't be called, is it correct?

Comment: Also I'm using post http method to establish persistent connection with server. May this influence on write callback somehow?

Comment: libcurl calls the write callback when it has received data from the server, chunked encoding or not. If you don't get the write callback invoked, something is truly wrong.

Comment: @DanielStenberg Just for clarification: When you say "without revealing the chunks to the application", does that mean libcurl will wait for all chunks to be received and the connection to be closed before calling the write callback?

Comment: @PhilippLudwig (are you seriously adding a question in a comment to a different question?) No I'm not saying that.